# How do I repeatedly throw a variable between 2 int functions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, int, void

I am trying to create a program that does the follow:
Each time the bus stops, it must load and unload passengers. The number of passengers that will be unloaded at every bus stop must be generated randomly. The number of passengers waiting for the bus at each stop is also generated randomly. The bus should load as many waiting passengers as possible without exceeding the bus capacity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void stop_bus(int); /* Stop the bus */ 
int unload_pass(int); /* Unload passengers */ 
int load_pass(int); /* Load passengers */ 
void start_bus(); /* Start the bus */


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int stops = 7, currentStop = 1;
    int maxPass = 50;

    load_pass(maxPass);
    while(currentStop < stops)
    {
        currentStop++;
        stop_bus(currentStop); 
        unload_pass(maxPass); 
        load_pass(maxPass); 
        //start_bus(); 
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void stop_bus(int currentStop)
{
    cout << "Currently at stop #" << currentStop << endl;
    cout << "Please disembark the bus in an orderly fashion." << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
int unload_pass(int maxPass)
{
    int passOff;
    int currentPass;
    currentPass = load_pass(maxPass);

    passOff = 1 + rand() % 50;
    while (currentPass - passOff > 0 )
    {
        cout << currentPass << ": That number is not in the range." << endl;
        passOff = 1 + rand() % 50;
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "People leaving the bus: " << passOff << endl;
    currentPass = currentPass - passOff;
    cout << "Current bus load is " << currentPass << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << currentPass << ": That number is not in the range" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return currentPass;
}
int load_pass(int maxPass)
{
    int passOn;
    int currentPass;
    currentPass = unload_pass(maxPass);

    passOn = 1 + rand() % 50;
    while (currentPass + passOn > maxPass)
    {
        cout << currentPass << ": That number is not in the range" << endl;
        passOn = 1 + rand() % 50;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "People boarding the bus: " << passOn << endl;
    currentPass = currentPass + passOn;
    cout << "Current bus load is "  << currentPass << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return currentPass;
}
```

I am positive that I am doing this incorrectly. when I try to run it, another window pops up telling me to break the code. What exactly does this mean and how might I resolve it?

Comment: "another window pops up telling me to break the code." Can you post the exact error message ?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly does the message say? If "break" means "stop" in this context then you probably have an infinite loop. From inspecting your code it looks like load_pass() starts with a call to unload_pass() which in turn starts with a call to load_pass() again.

This is essentailly an infinite recursion and will likely result in the error you are seeing.

Do you see any output from your print statements? That would be another good clue.

Comment: [http://i.imgur.com/2593kBr.jpg](This) pops up and does not allow anything to display.

Comment: That confirms user832981's guess . THe first thing `load_pass` does is to call `unload_pass`; and the first thing `unload_pass` does is to call `load_pass`. Obviously this is an infinite loop. You will have to re-think the logical steps that these functions are supposed to be doing.

Comment: I'm not yet sure how I could update a variable in 'unload_pass', call it in 'load_pass', and update it there as well. DO you know how I could do this, or better yet what it is called so I can look it up?

Comment: You need to store the current number of passengers in a variable and either pass that variable into the functions or make the variable global so that you can access it from anywhere. Note that global variable usually make you code worse so you probably don't want to do that. Another option would be to create a bus class and put the variable and functions in that class, but you will need to learn object oriented programming techniques for that.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

```
int unload_pass(int maxPass)
{
    int passOff;
    int currentPass;
    currentPass = load_pass(maxPass);
```

and

```
int load_pass(int maxPass)
{
    int passOn;
    int currentPass;
    currentPass = unload_pass(maxPass);
```

These two functions are calling each other until you get a stack overflow.

To figure out what your problems are run your code in the debugger, watch the call stack, inspect the variable values, etc.

Comment: How might I be able to use this variable in between them? The variable _currentPass_ is supposed to hold a number of less than 50. In **unload_pass** it should subtract from 'currentPass' whereas **load_pass** should add to _currentPass_